# Params too big for chain in Grails

Tags: grails, param, chain

I am sending an XML file using chain in Grails like so:

```
 chain(controller:"somecontroller", action:"someaction", params:[wib:wib.encodeAsURL()])
```

Where `wib` is an XML string. When I use a smaller XML string this works fine. 
It is worth noting that the XML string is about 50kb in size.

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

It doesn't even get to the next action.
I personally thing it is to do with the size of the URL in my browser.

Answer (score 3):

Since the chain method issues an HTTP redirect sending 50kb worth of information in the parameters (query parameters) isn't going to work. I seem to recall the maximum limit is somewhere around 4,000 characters for the entire query string.

That said, you may have better luck passing that data in a model, but still that's going to be putting all that data into session (flash) scope.

You can read more about the options for chain in the Grails [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/chain.html).